# Codeigniter join two tables display category name and list all items

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

1. Category:

   - cat_id
   - cat_name
2. Items

   - items_it
   - item_name
   - item_cat

I would like to get this result:

> Category->cat_name1
>    - item_name1
>    - item_name2
>
> Category->cat_name2
>    - item_name3
>    - item_name4

With PHP I would go with something like this:

```
$query1 = 'SELECT *FROM Category';
foreach($query1 as $cat) { 
    $query2 = 'SELECT *FROM Items WHERE "item_cat" = $cat';

    echo $cat;
    foreach($query2 as $item) {
    echo $item;
    }
}
```

What is the best approach for this using CODEIGNITER?

Comment: Is `item_cat` the same as `cat_id`? Because you need to have an equal column in both tables to be able to join them.. I sugest you have the same name in both tables for equal columns, that way it would be easier to understand the code :)

Comment: Yes, it's the same. I can join tables but I want to echo first category and all items in this category, than second category and all items in second category

Comment: And you want to echo the data in a list right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple example in Codeigniter with your schema:

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');     // select all columns
$this->db->from('Category'); // FROM table
$this->db->join('Items', 'Items.item_cat = Category.cat_id'); // INNER JOIN
$query = $this->db->get(); // GET RESULT
?>
```

For getting result, you can use two approaches, either want to get data in object form or in an array.

*In Array, use `result_array()` method, like:*

```
$result = $query->result_array();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); // will print all data in array
```

*In Object, use `result()` method, like:*

```
$result = $query->result();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); // will print all data in object
```

*Now you can sort as you want:*

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$value['cat_name']][] = $value; // sort as per category name
}
print_r($newArray); // will print all data against each category.
```

*Now print your required result as:*

```
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."<br/>"; // print Category Name
    foreach ($value as $final_value) {
        echo $final_value['item_name']."<br/>"; // print all items against category
    }
}
```

**[Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)** explore the documentation this will help you more to understand, how can you utilize the `INNER` or `LEFT` join CI.

Comment: Yea, using JOIN tables, but in this case, how can I echo first category and after that all items in this category?

Comment: @Pecooou, just `print_r($query)` will return all story.

Comment: Thanks mate, associative array is solution

Comment: @Pecooou, glad to help u dear

Comment: bro your answer works like a charm, but can you elaborate that how does the sorting inside the for loop works for each category ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a join:

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->join('items as i', 'i.item_cat = c.cat_id');
$query = $this->db->get('category as c');

foreach($query->result() as $result){
    echo $result->cat_name;
    echo $result->item_name;
}
```

Comment: In this case I will get:  category1  item1  category1 item2    what I need is category1 to echo only once for all items in that category