# I can't select two table in codeligniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a challenge for a job and my mission is to perform a CRUD using codeigniter. And in this challenge, I have to make a listing of two MYSQL tables, one with the name "deliverer" and the other "address".

The problem is that I am not able to make the connection in the database with the two tables. I'll show you how my Controller and my Model are.

Model:

```
public function SelecionaTodos() {

    $retorno = $this->db->get('entregador',100);  *I NEED TO CONNECT THE DELIVERY TABLE AND ADDRESS *

    return $retorno->result();

}
```

Controller:

public function index() {

```
    $this->load->model('EntregadorModel');

    $tabela = $this->EntregadorModel->SelecionaTodos();

    $dados = array(
        'titulo' => 'Lista de Entregadores',
        'tabela' => $tabela,
        'pagina' => 'entregador/index.php'
    );

    $this->load->view('index',$dados);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're trying to create one listing with data from both the `deliverer` and the `address` table, you need to use a join. Scroll down to `$this->db->join()` or search for `join` in this section: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->join()`

Permits you to write the JOIN portion of your query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('deliverers'); //Lista de Entregadores
$this->db->join('address', 'address.id = deliverer.id');

foreach($query->result() as $result){
    echo $result->deliverer;
    echo $result->address;
}
// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM deliverer ON deliverer.id = address.id
```

Multiple function calls can be made if you need several joins in one query.

If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, right outer and full outer.

also you can check : [Join two tables display category name and list all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074992/codeigniter-join-two-tables-display-category-name-and-list-all-items) and [Join not working with columns same name and id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590269/codeigniter-join-not-working-with-columns-same-name-and-id?rq=1)